# Autopep8/Flake8/isort: How do I sort using autoformatting absolute imports for user defined modules in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I am facing a formatting issue. The default behavior of `python.sortImports` is to organize stdlib, 3rd party, and user modules.

However,  it moves my user modules above the 3rd part modules in alphabetical order which is not according to PEP8. And, it follows PEP8 when I use relative imports which is making things more difficult.

My VS Code settings are mentioned below.

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
"files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
"python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true,
        "python.sortImports": true
    }
},
"python.globalModuleInstallation": true,
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/",
"python.analysis.extraPaths": "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/",
"isort.check": true,
"isort.args": ["--profile", "django"],
"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths":
{
      "name": "sklearn",
      "depth": 2
},
{
    "name": "matplotlib",
    "depth": 2
},
{
    "name": "scipy",
    "depth": 2
},
{
    "name": "django",
    "depth": 3
}
,
"python.analysis.indexing": true,
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or missing something that is obvious because I have been trying to solve it for the past two days?

Here, is the desired output.

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from customauth.views import ListUsers, RegisterUser
```

`customauth` is a user defined Django app, rest of them are 3rd part as you can see.

Actual output of `python.sortImports`.

```
from customauth.views import ListUsers, RegisterUser
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
```

**Note: I have figured out that this is an `isort` issue. But do not know why this is happening**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I fixed it myself. For future readers. If a local folder is showing up as a 3rd party library then use the following args in your *settings.json* file.

```
{
    "isort.args": [
        "--profile",
        "django",
        "--known-local-folder",
        "my_folder1",
        "--known-local-folder",
        "my_folder2",
        "--known-local-folder",
        "my_folder3"
    ],
}
```